# R crashes when trying to load CSV file

Tags: read.csv

When I try to read a CSV file using
**read.csv(file="/Users/User1/Documents/file.csv", header=T)**
it says no file path exists. This command works with the same file when I tried it on a different computer.

So I tried **read.csv(file.choose())**, but this just freezes my console. This command works on the other computer with the same file.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the program and even tried an older version of R, but the problem persists.

I cannot change my working directory either. **setwd()** also freezes the console.

Has anyone had this same problem?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I have faced the same problem while having a big chunk of data. The loading process also creates pressure on the computer so you need to check your ram, storage and the processor of your computer. So, I'll recommend you to work on python, otherwise, you can have a try with the h2o server. Google about how to do the analysis using the h2o server in R. It may also work.